# Issue with Daimons in Dragonbane

Tags: acheron, dark-hunter

If the Dark-Hunters life mission is to destroy the Daimons, then

> why did Savitar and others agree to search for a cure for the plague they've been infected with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollymi asked him to and evidently, he can't refuse her anything

> She returned her attention to Savitar. “It would seem Apollo unleashed
>   a nasty disease among the Apollites here. We’ve already lost a number
>   of them to it. Many more are sick. The only ones who appear immune are
>   Medea and Stryker, no doubt because they’re his children. Even Zephyra
>   is ill. I’ve tried everything I know to offer a cure, but I’m not a
>   goddess of healing.”
>
> “Is it a curse or a plague?”
>
> “The Greek bastard called it a plague. An illness, I presume. Can you
>   help them? Please.”
>
> **Those were words he could never ignore when she uttered them. For her,
>   there was nothing he wouldn’t do. “Absolutely. I’ll do everything I
>   can.”**

Comment: **Disclaimer** - Warning - I know nothing about this book series.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if that meant he was compelled or he didn't want to deny her. It seems counterproductive to the entire cause

Comment: @Ali666 - He seems smitten with her. Not compelled, but certainly desperate in his urge to please.